# Find the complex roots of the equation

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis, functions

Find the roots of the following equation. I keep getting tripped up over the polar form and am not sure what to do with obtaining $\theta=0$. Cheers!

$$z^4+2=0$$

Where $z=x+iy$.

Comment: Hint: Try $x=z^2$.

Comment: You should get your terminology straight. That's not a complex number, that's an equation with complex roots.

Comment: @Atvin, unless Im doing it incorrectly I then obtain +\-(2)^(1\2)i, which doesnt solve the equation.

Comment: @Henrik, you´re right! I got quite confused myself over the terminology after searching online for possible help kept returning results on the roots of complex numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases like these, it helps to have a standard method. First start by rearranging to:

$z^4 = -2$.

Next express the RHS into exponential complex form. Remember that $-1 = e^{i\pi} = e^{i\pi + 2k\pi i} = e^{i\pi (2k+1)}$, where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. The reason for introducing that $k$ is so that no solutions are missed when the root is taken (it'll become clearer soon).

Now take the roots of both side:

$$z = 2^{\frac 14}e^{i\pi \frac{(2k+1)}{4}}$$

All you have to do is put consecutive values for $k$ starting from $0$ until the value repeats (it's periodic). You expect four roots, so $k=0,1,2,3$ should be what you expect here.

That gives the four roots as $z = 2^{\frac 14}e^{ \frac{i\pi}{4}},2^{\frac 14}e^{ \frac{3i\pi}{4}}, 2^{\frac 14}e^{ \frac{5i\pi}{4}}, 2^{\frac 14}e^{ \frac{7i\pi}{4}}$ which are all unique in rectangular form, so those are your four roots. When $k =4$, you get $z = 2^{\frac 14}e^{ \frac{9i\pi}{4}} = 2^{\frac 14}e^{ \frac{i\pi}{4}}$ so that's when it starts repeating.

If you want to express the roots in rectangular form (i.e. $z = x+yi$), just use Euler's formula $e^{i\theta} = \cos\theta + i\sin\theta$.

Comment: that has made it so much more clearer, I understand it perfectly now, thank you very much!

Comment: @Jeremy Most welcome! :)

Answer (score 1):

From your equation we get,

$z^4=-2$ , 
Now here's the trick,

Let $-2= 2e^{i(2n-1)\pi}$ where $n\in N$.

We will get,

$z^4=2\times e^{i(2n-1)\pi}$

Taking fourth root both side,

$z= 2^{1/4} \times e^{\frac{i(2n-1)\pi}{4}}$ , this will have four distinct solution. $i.e.,$ take $n=1,2,3,4$

Comment: I see you used the alternative form of De Moivre's theorem. Could you explain for me please why you used (2n-1). This is where when I tried to find theta I obtained theta=0, which I thought was wrong. Thanks again!

Comment: Carefully look for value of $e^{i\pi}$ and note that this value is periodic for $\pm 2\pi$ @Jeremy :)

Comment: okay, I think I get it now, thanks a lot!

Comment: $e^{i\cdot0} = 1, e^{i\pi} = -1$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** DeMoivre's Theorem will solve this.

**Solution:** If $z = r\cdot (\cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta)$ then $z^4 = r^4 \cdot (\cos(4\theta) + i\sin(4\theta))$. Since $z^4 = - 2$ we want $r^4 = 2 \implies r = \sqrt[4]{2}$ and $\cos(4\theta) + i\sin(4\theta) = \cos((2n-1)\pi) + i\sin((2n-1)\pi)$ or $\theta = \frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{3\pi}{4},\frac{5\pi}{4}, \frac{7\pi}{4}$ for $\theta$ in $[0,2\pi)$.

Comment: That last value is $7\pi/4$ ? I guess.

Comment: You are correct, sorry for the typo